# Change the date for the 1st record of a link in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, rank

I have query where i want to change the SALES_DATE to `'01.01.1800'` for the 1st record for a product. It means i want to get all the unique product which is stored in `PRODUCT_ID` and check the first `SALES_DATE` on which the product is loaded and change this `SALES_DATE` to `'01.01.1800'`. I believe i can use `RANK` function but i haven't used before and there might be another good solution for which i am trying to write the query for this. THE `PRODUCT_ID` value is not unique in this column.

```
Select PRODUCT_ID,SALES_DATE from SALES_DETAILS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for RANK, you can get the lowest dates using a Correlated Subquery:

```
select *
from sales_details as sd
where sales_date <> date '1800-01-01' -- don't update if there's already a row with that date
  and sales_date = -- find the row with the lowest date
      ( select min(sales_date)
        from sales_details as sd2
        where sd.product_id = sd2.product_id
      )
```

When you checked it's the correct data simply switch to an UPDATE:

Comment: How do we know for which products the SALES_DATE is not '01.01.1800'. Because i want to update those only. Your query gives all the product_id but with date '01.01.1800' also

Comment: Why do you have sales data going back to the 18th century?

Comment: Actually this product is not valid anymore and needs to be there in the database but with the some expired odd date

Comment: @Andrew: No, no, no, that's not the way this is usually done, product info is usually stored in a Slowly Changing Dimension with a `valid_from/valid_to` and `valid_to` is set to *infinity* for active rows and the closing date for closed rows.

Comment: i put the condition for sd.sales_date <> DATE '1800-01-01''. Will it be problem ?

Comment: @Andrew: No, that's correct, my previous comment was wrong. `sales_date <> DATE '1800-01-01` must be added to the *outer* Select. That's why you should test the result before you run the actual Update :-)